# How Can I Update a React Context with a Descendant's State?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

My app is set up like so:

```
   <MainContext.Provider value={//the value should come from <Comp2>}>
    <App>
     <Comp1 p={{contextValue}}><Comp1>
     <Comp2></Comp2>
     <Comp3></Comp3>
    </App>
   </MainContext.Provider>
```

I would like to have `<Comp2>` provide it's state to `MainContext` so that `<Comp1>` and `<Comp3>` have access to it.
So far every explanation has the value come from the main `<App>` state which is not the case for me. I also can't make `<Comp2>` the parent since they will all become routes.

Thank you.

Comment: React Context Provider or Redux.

Comment: Context Provider